# Appended items on text file, won't sort, but the original data on text file is sorted

Tags: c, file-processing

After appending data, the problem appears.
 
1) I cannot read that data, that I append. I have to close the program, and then open it again so that it read the new data. 
 2) After i opened it again, to look at the new data, it won't sort, but all other data in the original text file is being sorted.
 I have the code, but it's too long, and messy. And it's not in English. 
https://codeshare.io/2WVv1l. 
I can't really explain what happened pretty well, and I can't seem to find any solutions online. 
I would love some tips or some speculation of what happening, even about small stuffs is okay :).

Comment: "it's too long, and messy. And it's not in English". In which case it is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can't dump 700 lines of code and expect someone else here to debug it for you. Even if someone kindly does that for you how about next time you have a bug? It's best if you learn better development practices (write small functions, test each part as you go, learn to use a debugger, etc). [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @kaylum I'm sorry, yup you're right , i think i'm giving up too soon.

Comment: The program doesn't increment the `size` variable after adding a new record, so the rest of the program has no idea that the `keg` array now contains an additional entry.